# What happens to the accuracy of a decision tree after pruning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cart, ensemble-learning, pruning

What happens to the accuracy of a decision tree when it is pruned? Can be higher than the accuracy of the fully-grown decision tree?

Comment: On the training set, no.

Comment: On the test set, often yes. This is why we prune in the first place.